# jQuery is doubling my cloning everytime I click a link to clone html?

Tags: jquery

The following html snippet contains an input, a select and a link. When I click the link, I want to basically clone line, I want the new line to be appended to the last line. I also would like the link to be removed and be added to the last line.  I want to have the even carried over as well.  I will put my jquery code below the html.

```
<div id="lines">
    <div class="line">
        <span>Value</span><input type="text" name="value" class="value"/>
        <span>Type</span>
        <select name="type" class="type">
        <option>$</option>
    <option>%</option>
    </select>
        <a id="addLine" href="#">Add</a>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#addLine').click(function() {

       $('.line').clone({withDataAndEvents:true}).appendTo('#lines');

    });
});
```

When I click add, it first adds a second line below the first one, but then when I click add again, it adds 2 lines, so I have 4, every time I click add, it is doubling the amount of lines which is what I don't want.  I also want add removed from all the lines except the last one.  I probably will have a Remove as well to remove a specific line, so I would like suggestions on how to handle this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you're cloning the whole element set with the `line` class, meaning the first time it adds one line, the second will add 2, the third will add 4.  You can fix this by just cloning one line with `.last`:

```
$('#addLine').click(function() {
    $('.line').last().clone({
        withDataAndEvents: true
    }).appendTo('#lines');
});
```

Comment: Oh no, I got dancing unicorns upon voting this up. What is the world coming to?

Comment: If I want to append the next line to the previous line instead of lines, how does that change the code.

Comment: Use `insertAfter(this)` instead of `appendTo('#lines')`

Answer (score 1):

the jquery selector $('.line') selects all items with a class of "line" as an array, then you clone and add the new array back the existing array.

what you want to do is $('.line')[0] in order to just clone the first item. (or which ever one line you wish to clone)

Cheers,

CEC

Comment: I would note that `$('line')[0]` returns the DOM element rather than the jquery object.

Comment: your right, however if you look closely at what I entered there is a period in there.. $('.line') not $('line')

Answer (score 0):

You're cloning everything with the .line class, so of course it's going to double on each run.  Narrow your results, possibly by changing the clone selector to

```
$('.line:first').clone({withDataAndEvents:true}).appendTo('#lines');
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It adds multiple `.line`'s because each time #addLine is clicked, `$('.line')` matches more and more elements.

What I would do is make a template to append to #lines each time, however, the easiest solution is to change `$('.line')` to `$('.line').last()`.

---

To get #addLine to only be on the last line,

- First, you need a live event:
  `$('#addLine').click(function() {` changes to 
  `$('#addLine').live('click', function() {`
- Second, within the event callback:

  ```
  var $newLine = $('.line').last().clone({withDataAndEvents:true});

  $("#addLine").remove();

  $newLine.appendTo('#lines');
  ```

Answer (score 0):

change your function to this:

```
$('#addLine').click(function() {

   $('.line:first-child').clone({withDataAndEvents:true}).appendTo('#lines');
});
```