# Add Struts 2 select drop down list dynamically using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have a `student.jsp` page that loads a select drop down list from the database Faculty

```
<s:select list="ftyList" name="fid" listKey="fid" listValue="name" label="Select a Faculty" />
```

Now, I've got to add more of the exact same drop down list when I click on Add button. For that I've got a `div` with Add button and my JavaScript code as below:

```
<div id="div">
    <button onclick="addListFunction()">Add</button>
</div>
```

addDropDown.js:

```
function addListFunction() {    
    var d = document.getElementById("div");
    d.innerHTML += "<p><s:select list='ftyList' name='fid' listKey='fid' listValue='name' label='Select a Faculty' /></p>";
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the 'Add' button it's only adding an empty space. When used firebug, I could see the Struts tag was being printed the same as above instead of HTML tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<s:select>` is a struts tag which cannot be added directly from javascript and assumed to run server side.

You can use [jQuery Clone method](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) when Add button is clicked.

```
<s:select list="ftyList" name="fid" listKey="fid" listValue="name" cssClass="fidSelect" label="Select a Faculty" />

function addListFunction() {    
    $('.fidSelect').clone().insertAfter(".fidSelect");
}
```

Comment: @Sujal 1. You have to include jquery script on the page. 2. You noticed he added `cssClass` to select tag

Comment: @Karthik the attribute name is `cssClass` not just `class`. I just corrected it.

Comment: @coding_idiot: Thanks a lot, that added the dropdownList although the problem now is that every time i click on the add button the number of added drop down list doubles. How do i fix this?

Comment: @Sujal here's the complete solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516610/jquery-is-doubling-my-cloning-everytime-i-click-a-link-to-clone-html

Answer (score 1):

You can try this uisng jQuery

```
function addListFunction() {

var optionList = [{"key":"1" , "value":"item1"},
                  {"key":"2" , "value":"item2"},
                  {"key":"3" , "value":"item3"},
                  {"key":"4" , "value":"item4"},
                  {"key":"5" , "value":"item5"},
                  {"key":"6" , "value":"item6"}];

var combo = $("<select>").attr("id", "inputAuto").attr("name", "selectTag");

$.each(optionList, function (j, el1) {
                var opt = $("<option>").attr("value",el1.key).append(el1.value);
                combo.append(opt);
         });

$("#DivId").append(combo);
}
```

In this i have statically define the array of option (e.g. optionList). But you can make an ajax call for this.

Comment: The problem isn't with adding static drop down list. Adding static drop down list works fine. I need to use struts <s:select> to display dynamically

Comment: all the struts tags are render on page load. our browser can't understand <s:...> tags.. so if you want to add <s:...> tags dynamically then you have to make a page refresh so that <s:...> tags can be render to simple HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

The struts tags are only interpretet once by the server before the page is delivered. If you manipulate the dom afterwards with JavaScript you can't use JSP Tags.

Comment: so is there any other way to do this?